# Why does VS2013 sometimes throws exception 0x80070057 when closing a file?

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2013

Sometimes, not all the time, Visual Studio 2013 w/ Update 1 on an up to date Win7 x64 machine throws an exception when closing a file, or multiple files doing "Close All But This". A dialog is shown referring you to the "ActivityLog.xml" file at "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0" which has one of the following entries for each file that was being closed. I am using the latest version of DevExpress controls.

How can I fix this? I did not find any similar issues though post [Is there something I can/should do about this VS 2013 exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521609/is-there-something-i-can-should-do-about-this-vs-2013-exception?rq=1) was vaguely similar but this does not happen when I open a solution.

So far, it seems to occur mostly when having multiple instances of VS2013 open but I am unable to repro at will. Clearing the ComponentModelCache did not help in that it has occurred again after clearing the cache. The solution was originally a VS2012 solution and all new DevX, MVC and EF components have been updated to latest versions with NuGet.

```
<entry>
<record>858</record>
<time>2014/02/17 20:22:45.177</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
<description>System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.NativeMethods.ThrowOnFailure(Int32 hr, Int32[] expectedHRFailure)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.RunningDocumentTable.FindDocument(String moniker, IVsHierarchy&amp; hierarchy, UInt32&amp; itemid, UInt32&amp; docCookie)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeSense.Editor.Roslyn.CodeElementTaggerProvider.CreateTagger(ITextView textView)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeSense.Editor.TaggerProvider`1.CreateTagger[T](ITextView textView, ITextBuffer buffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer textBuffer)</description>
```

Comment: I have not installed alpha versions of anything that I know of unless you mean MVC5. Nor anything known (by me) to cause trouble. I did not specifically install anything with Roslyn that I know of and did not even know what it was till I looked it up.

Comment: Roslyn ships indirectly in Visual Studio 2013 as the backing analysis engine for features like Code Lens / Sense.  This appears to be what is happening here

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? And what happened to the previous comment about my supposedly installing alpha software?

Comment: I think the presence of the string "Roslyn" in the error message was throwing people off.  It made it look like you'd installed alpha software and then asked about things breaking (which would be expected).  Most people don't realize that Roslyn shipped in part as an implementation artifact of other Visual Studio features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the Code Sense engine.  They are requesting a document from the Running Document Table after the document has been closed.  I encourage you to please file a bug on this (customer bugs get more attention than if I just filed it)

> http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

The only thing you can do to stop this is to disable Code Sense

- Tools -> Options
- Text Editor -> All Languages -> Code Lens
- Uncheck "Enable CodeLens"